# Is it possible to stretch an element or pseudo element till the horizontal page boundary without using overflow-x:hidden

Tags: css

I normally use a wrapping container element and use `margin: 0 auto;` to get flexible extending margins on both sides. In the present case i wanted an element to stretch till one boundary of the page. I've sized it far larger with a width of around 999em and then cut the `overflow` with `overflow-x:hidden`.

http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/omueg

Problem is i've learned that that the `overflow` property is kind of buggy especially in webkit based browsers and gets ignored completely. But now i try to accomplish the task otherwise but am kind of lost and out of ideas. I've created a sample in codepen:

http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/fyLrn

The code i've used for the pseudo element version is:

```
<section>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

the css looks like

```
.wrap {
  background-color:red;
  width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40rem;
}

section {
  padding-top:4rem;
  width:100%;
  background-color: green;
  height:40rem;
}

.box {
    height: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
    position:relative;
    text-align: left;
    top: 0;
    left:17.75rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    background-color:grey;
    width:15rem;
    &:after {
        content: "";
        position:absolute;
        background-color:blue;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        width: 35rem;
        left:100%;
    }
}
```

But i could also remove the `:after` pseudo element completely and set a larger width on the `.box`class. But either way it wouldn't help to span the element to the right boundary. Is it possible at all to get the grey box (without the pseudo element) or the blue box (with the pseudo element) to stretch always till the right boundary of the page?

Comment: "*i wanted an element to stretch till one boundary of the page.*". I don't know what you want to say with this. Can you explain this more simple?

Comment: Where did you read that `overflow` is buggy in webkit browsers?

Comment: @NicoO i just meant that the blue box is stretched till the page boundary on the right like here http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/jkuxa . But my goal is to reach that without the overflow hidden property and the extensive large width on the pseudo element like in the pen in my comment here.

Comment: @MarcAudet When searching for a solution for my initial layout http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/omueg i stumbled across comments regarding troubles with the overflow-x:hidden property. And well if i test the pen in Safari, Webkit Nightly, Chrome, Opera, Opera Next all fail to behave correctly. Only Firefox behaves as expected. IE i haven't tested yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/xckL79he/4/ ?

I used a second div to do that because the main problem is that the .box have a defined width so the pseudo element will have the same on a width:100%;
First solution with pseudo, and a second with a background-gradient (less safe i think).

Here is the Code of the Fiddle

HTML

```
<section>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="boxContainer">
          <div class="box">Plop</div>
      </div>
      <br /><br />
      <div class="boxContainerGradient">
          <div class="box">Plop</div>
      </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  padding-top:4rem;
  width:100%;
  background-color: green;
  height:40rem;
}

.wrap {
  background-color:red;
  width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40rem;
}

.boxContainer{
    position:relative;
}
.boxContainer::before {
        content: "";
        position:absolute;
        background-color:blue;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        width: 50%;
        height:100%;
}
.box{
    height: 3.5rem;
    line-height: 3.5rem;
    position:relative;
    text-align: left;
    margin:auto;
    width:15rem;
}

.boxContainerGradient{
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,255,0) 49%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,255,0)), color-stop(49%,rgba(0,0,255,0)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,0) 49%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,0) 49%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,0) 49%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,255,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,255,0) 49%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000ff', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */


}
```

Comment: Sorry. I think i've explained it in a bad way :( I meant refering to your fiddle that the blue :after container goes till the window border on the right and not only to the wrap border.

Comment: Oh ! I see.. that is one more lvl upper haha ! sorry ^^'